# fill NaNs+1 in vector equaly

Tags: octave

I have a vector of measured values. Sometimes the system failed, so it's NaN. The next time the system restarted, the data from the cache is written to the vector as a sum all at once.

Now I want to find those (check), and fill them with the sum, divided by the number of NaNs in a row +1, so that the sum from the cache does not create a peak but a constant.

```
data = [1 4 7 2 NaN 9 8 4 NaN NaN NaN 90]'

idx_errorPLS=(find(isnan(data)))

idx_restartPLS=(find(isnan(data))+1)
```

Now I got the indices of the errors and the (possible) restart-indices. But I don't know how to go on...

Maybe it's even a sub-optimal approach...?

edit: I want to edit the value after the NaN(s), too. So that the example-data look like `data = 1 4 7 2 4.5 4.5 8 4 22.5 22.5 22.5 22.5`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the descriptions of both [tag:matlab] and [tag:octave]. They are **not** the same, thus please only use both tags when asking about the similarities/differences between the two. Using both tags could result in answers being incompatible to the other software, unnecessarily forcing answerers to check validity of their code in both programs.

Comment: It's a bit unclear to me. On your exemple input data, could you show which result you are expecting at the end?

Comment: Hi, shure! I want it like ```data = 1 4 7 2 4.5 4.5 8 4 22.5 22.5 22.5 22.5```

Comment: How do you get to 4.5 and 22.5? You’re it using the sum of all non-nan values in the array. What then is “the sum”?

Comment: Matlab and the Octave statistics package have the fillmissing function that has a number of options for what to fill the missing data with. It might have an option that fits your needs

Comment: Would you mind giving feedback to the people who took time to help you?

Comment: It looks like you don't mind...

Answer (score 0):

About the question "is it an optimal approach (to change values like this)?", only you know...

About how to do it: I don't think it's possible without any explicit loop.

```
n =  length(data);
j = 1;
while j <= n
    if isnan(data(j))
        firstnan = j;
        while j < n && isnan(data(j+1))
            j++;
        end
        lastnan = j;
        if lastnan < n
            data(firstnan:lastnan+1) = data(lastnan+1) / (lastnan-firstnan+2);
        elseif firstnan > 1
            data(firstnan-1:lastnan) = data(firstnan-1) / (lastnan-firstnan+2);
        else
            disp "no replacement possible";
        end
    endif
    j++;
end
```

If the last element is a NaN I am using the element before the NaNs to replace the values. If there are only NaNs obviously no replacement is possible.